# HttpClient POST multiple objects/variables

Tags: c#, variables, post, httpclient

I'm using HttpClient to connect .NET project with my Web API.

Thing is, that i can't make it work when sending multiple variables or objects.
With one parameter i do like this:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            int systemId = 24;

            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/method/{id}", systemId).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Do
            }
            else
                // DO
        }
```

With several variables, i can't make ir work. I don't get how to send several variables. It may be one Object and Byte[] or two integers and similar. Uri would be like: "Api/Method/{SystemId}/{Id}.

Maybe [FromBody] attribute could help me in this solution ? And how do i make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Api/Method/{id} is URL Route Pattern that will automatically bind a request parameter with the exactly name "id". However if the API Method has an object as parameter and you pass into you request an object with the same attribute names (you can use a JSON object) you will have what you want.

Comment: Yes i know how it works with one object or variable. But how to pass multiple variables/objects if the URL route Pattern is like "Api/Method/{systemID}/{ID}

Comment: You should create this URL pattern in your API project, and on the post request, pass a systemID parameter and ID parameter. Example: systemID=120&ID=999

Comment: Yeah. I just tried to did it similar to your example. Bind values in the Url and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "MyAPIRoute",
                url: "Api/Method/{SystemId}/{Id}"

            );
```

You can call it, binding the SystemId and Id parameter with Query String:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

        int systemId = 24;
        int id = 45;
        string queryString = "SystemId="+systemId+"&Id="+id;

        var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/method/",queryString).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Do
        }
        else
            // DO
    }
```